# How do you track down kernel panic issues?

Tags: mac, kernel, console, kernel-panic

I've got a mac running as an office server which has it's share of kernel panics. I've tried reviewing the last item in the Console but I'm not sure if that's what I'm actually looking for or which log to review.

Is there a general way to track down kernel panics on a Mac?

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Is this OSX server?

Comment: After finding the panic logs in /Library/Logs/PanicReporter, paste some of them here (or on pastebin or as a github gist) and see what others can glean from it. If it contains a list of kernel loadable modules in the backtrace, that may give you a hint as to what hardware device driver has the crashing bug you're hitting.

Answer (score 1):

Check the panic reports in /Library/Logs/PanicReporter; they'll contain information about the kernel stack at the time of the panic, which may (or may not) have information pointing at the cause.

Other than that, general troubleshooting principles apply: did anything change around the time the panics started?  Can you take the server down long enough to run hardware tests (esp. RAM and CPU)?  Note that the install DVD that shipped with the Mac should have diagnostics available if you boot from the DVD with the "d" key held down.